# Saving super() return value in Django's Mixins

Tags: python, django

I want to create DRY Django Mixins for things I do frequently. I have multiple `Access Mixins` that all need current `Organization`, so I wanted the code responsible for getting the `Organization` to be in separate Mixin, that also inherits from Djangos `LoginRequiredMixin`, because we will always check that if we're in organization page.

But instead of preforming `dispatch` method of inherited classes, saving the response and doing its thing, it skips it.
I started reading about Python's `MRO` and all, but I still can't find a way to make it all work.

Is my basic idea wrong? What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Paweł

Code:

```
class OrganizationMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    """
    CBV mixin for getting current organization.
    Inherits from `LoginRequiredMixin` because we need logged in user to check
    their membership and/or organization role.
    """
    org_kwarg_name = 'organization_slug'
    organization = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.organization = self.get_organization()
        return response

    def get_organization(self):
        # Get the slug from URL
        slug = self.kwargs.get(self.org_kwarg_name, None)
        return get_object_or_404(Organization, slug=slug)


class MembershipRequiredMixin(OrganizationMixin, AccessMixin):
    """
    CBV mixin for checking if user belongs to current organization.
    Already checks if user is logged in.
    """
    permission_denied_message = _("You need to belong to the organization "
                                  "to visit this page.")

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # Check if user is a member or a superuser
        if (not self.organization.is_member(request.user) and
                not request.user.is_superuser):
            return self.handle_no_permission()

        return response
```

Comment: @AviahLaor from my understanding, Python 3 uses `super()` syntax

Comment: You should check for membership _before_ you call `super()`. Otherwise, any view that changes data will change that data even if the user doesn't have permission to do so.

Comment: @knbk but if I run the `MembershipRequiredMixin` code before calling `super()`, then the `OrganizationMixin` code won't execute and `self.organization` won't be set.

Comment: That's super. One of the rare annoying things in Python

Comment: @pawel.ad Then refactor. You can call `self.get_organization()` in `MembershipRequiredMixin` before youc all `super()` or check for membership.

Comment: maybe dispatch is bind when the urls are loaded with as_view(), and from then on, the url resolves to the first dispatch in the chain?  "The as_view entry point creates an instance of your class and calls its dispatch() method"